# Scheme: car and cdr

Tags: scheme

I'm reading this book:
http://www.shido.info/lisp/scheme3_e.html

I'm stuck on this exercise:

```
(car '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
```

The thing is, from my understanding, I must understand how do we get ((1 2 3) (4 5 6)) to get (car '((1 2 3) (4 5 6))) because *car* evaluates the first address.

I tried a few times but cannot get the exact "string" (I don't even know how to call them):

```
(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '()))) (cons 4 (cons 5 (cons 6 '()))))
```

gives me

```
{{1 2 3} 4 5 6}

(cons (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '()))) '()) (cons 4 (cons 5 (cons 6 '()))))
```

gives me

```
{{{1 2 3}} 4 5 6}

(cons (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '()))) '()) (cons (cons 4 (cons 5 (cons 6 '()))) '()))
```

gives me

```
{{{1 2 3}} {4 5 6}}
```

At least I'm getting brackets for both parts...

The thing is, if each time I call *car* to get the first address, I need to formulate the result in my head to see the other side of the mountain, this seems to be an extremely difficult language to me...so I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a a very good book (for instance, "address"  is a word you never hear in connection with Scheme). The excellent books [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html) and [How to Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org) are available online, and are both among the best programming books you can find.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks I'm actually preparing to read sicp after this. Heard that sicp doesn't teach much scheme grammar so I grabbed a grammar book. Might be wrong though.

Comment: The Lisp family has a very simple grammar; it's impossible to write a book without covering all of it. I would recommend that you either start with HtDP (it's a bit "friendlier") or go directly to SICP. They are both much easier to read (they were written by experts whose native language is English), contain far fewer errors, and they both contain lots of meaningful exercises.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ah thank you! Will read SICP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'((1 2 3) (4 5 6))` is `(cons (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '()))) (cons (cons 4 (cons 5 (cons 6 '()))) '()))`

```
> (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '()))) (cons (cons 4 (cons 5 (cons 6 '()))) '()))
'((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
```

If we replace the inner lists with symbols because their value does not matter we get:

```
(car '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
(car '(X Y))
(car (cons 'X (cons 'Y '())))
```

Which by the reduction `(car (cons A B)) => A` produces `'X` so the result is `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))` or `'(1 2 3)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The explanation dispels some of my doubt, but I must say in general I'm still pretty confused about the parenthesis. For example I don't get why they show in every result, and what does *cons* do and why do we need it, quite confused. It seems to be, well, a list, but I'm familiar with the C/C++ list with a pointer to the next node and a container for the actual data. I'll read a few more chapters and see if I can grasp the concept better. BTW I'm using DrRacket so I'm actually seeing curly.

Comment: Sorry cannot edit the previous comment. I got the idea of curly brackets. If it's a *cons* then it has curly brackets. E.g. (car (cons (cons 1 '()) 2)) gives {1} because that is a *cons*, while (car (cons 1 2)) gives 1 because that is *inside* of a *cons*. I think the brackets are the way to tell *elements* of a construction from a construction itself. Now if we go back to the original question, {{1 2 3} {4 5 6}} definitely has two elements, first one must be a *cons* as {1 2 3} is in curly brackets, and second is the same. I still don't get why my first answer does not give the right output.